# Panda Data Frame plotting - column value as index

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dataframe

I want to plot multiple data using data from a column as series.

For example, my raw data:

```
Date,       SomeName,   SomeData
2015-1-1,   Vancouver,  1.1
2015-1-2,   NYC,        1.2
2015-1-3,   Seattle,    2.1
2015-1-4,   Vancouver,  0.9
2015-1-5,   Seattle,    1.1
2015-1-2,   NYC,        2.1
```

If I were to use Excel, with Pivot Chart, I would choose 'Date' to be X-axis, 'SomeName' to be Series(Legend), and 'SomeData' to be 'Values'.

But how do I do something similar with Pandas.plot module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do exactly the same as you would do in Excel, except that pivot chart is explicitly a pivot table you subsequently plot:

```
df.pivot_table('SomeData', 'Date', 'SomeName').plot.bar()
```

[image: result]
￼

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the easiest way is to try seaborn, which is a wrapper on matplotlib (as is the pandas plotting function).

You'll have to install it with `pip install seaborn` or `conda install seaborn`, and then you can do:

`import seaborn as sns`

`sns.factorplot(x='Date', y='SomeData', hue='SomeName', data=df)`